# select with condition -Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `test` as the following

```
Contract   date_prolog    hours 
-------------------------------
No                         20
Yes         24/02/2014     10
No                         30
No                         10
```

How can I get this results ?

```
Contract   date_prolog    hours 
-------------------------------
No          24/02/2014     20
No          24/02/2014     30
No          24/02/2014     10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select contract, 
       (select date_prolog from test where contract = 'yes') as date_prolog, 
       hours
from test
where contract = 'no'
```